# Windows Phone Offline Update

Tags: lumia, windows-10-mobile, update

Just a quick Question though.

Is it possible to do an offline update of any lumia phone like we install custom roms in Android mobiles? I've a Microsoft Lumia 640 XL Dual sim with Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2, and wanted to update it to Windows 10 without using Wifi or Data Connection in phone (assume that I might have limits for using both).

Can we download an ISO or such file(s) from Microsoft (either official update or preview builds), copy it to phone's SD/Internal Memory (if no SD support) and then update from there?

I googled and i couldn't find a proper answer anywhere.

Comment: The recovery tool includes command-line tools for pushing both full ROMs and update packages. Downloading the correct set of update packages for your phone is not documented anywhere that I know of, but on the XDA-Developers forum you can find people who make a list of the download URLs for their updates so you *might* be able to do this. How were you planning to get the updates onto your computer, if even your WiFi is limited?

Comment: what if the WiFi is limited in office and unlimited net connection for a desktop pc, and can't use data in mobile for some reason?

Comment: ... that still sounds very weird, but assuming it's real and the limitation is bad enough to matter here (the updates are big but not *that* big), I'd suggest using Internet connection sharing from a desktop (if it has WiFi or Bluetooth) or from a laptop that you plug into the wired Ethernet. To share your PC's connection over WiFi, you might find [Virtual Router Manager](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no offline update option available currently.

I too faced a similar need when installing some big updates as I didnot have access to Wi-Fi. If not having Wi-Fi is your problem then there is a workaround. Warning : This may consumes a lot of data.

1. Go to Data usage in settings.
2. Turn on the option to allow Mobile data when there is limited or no Wi-Fi.
3. Click on *Set limit* option and set data plan to unlimited.
4. This helped me sometimes(not everytime). For example the upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows phone 8.1 still required Wi-Fi.

On the other hand as Mr.Krishna said, you can use Windows device recovery tool but it will install the OS the phone is shipped with. It can be useful to update the phones that came with Windows 10 Mobile OS out of box.

Answer (score 3):

Download the Windows Recovery Tool to your computer.

Connect your Windows Phone to the PC with the USB Cable.

After the phone is detected, tap the phone model on the screen to continue.

But its online not Offline.

Comment: This will reset to the original OS version. not update.

Comment: its possible using a software called windows phone internals, but i dunno any source for roms, this link might help you. http://thehackernews.com/2015/11/root-windows-phone.html

Comment: @RamRaj Yeah. But I neither want to root, nor want to install custom roms. All I wanted to do is offline update of Windows Phone.